# Counting keys and storing them to corresponding values

Tags: python, function, dictionary, count

What I want to do: filter a certain column of data, split these tweets into 2 as positives and negatives, store these as positive and negative words in a dictionary, and count each word in either positive or negative subset and write the number in the value corresponding to that word in dictionary. keep in mind that this is my homework and I can only change the code between #'s. I probably make a mistake after 'for', but could not quite get why.

```
def get_counts(data):

    counts the number of times a word appears in negative or positive tweets

    Parameters:
    data: Pandas dataframe of tweets

    Returns:
    counts: Dictionary of counts, which includes the dictionaries 'pos' and 'neg'



    counts = {"pos":{}, "neg":{}}
    # Your code goes here
    poscol=sentiment_data.loc[sentiment_data['a']>2,['f']] #here I filter positive tweets
    negcol=sentiment_data.loc[sentiment_data['a']<2,['f']] #here I filter negative tweets
    possen=''.join(poscol['f']) #I merge these tweets into one string 
    negsen=''.join(negcol['f'])
    pos1 = word_tokenize(possen) #I tokenize these words so that I can make each of them keys of the dict
    neg1 = word_tokenize(negsen)
    pos = dict.fromkeys(pos1, [0]) #I create dicts with keys and absent values.
    neg = dict.fromkeys(neg1, [0])
    for a in counts:
            if a in pos1:
                counts['pos'][a] == pos1.count('a')
            if a in neg1:
                counts['neg'][a] += neg1.count('a')
    return counts

# Do not change
counts = get_counts(sentiment_data)
print(counts["pos"]["happy"]) # should print 124
print(counts["neg"]["hate"]) # should print 99
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-e732b4029bae> in <module>
     33 # Do not change
     34 counts = get_counts(sentiment_data)
---> 35 print(counts["pos"]["happy"]) # should print 124
     36 print(counts["neg"]["hate"]) # should print 99

KeyError: 'happy'
```

Comment: Did you mean to use a `+=` or a `==`?

Comment: you are right, I meant += for counts['pos'][a] == pos1.count('a')

Comment: ***"KeyError: 'happy'"***: You didn't define the expected **keys**. Do 'print(counts)', just before `return counts`, to see what you have defiend.

Comment: It did not do any difference. when I print counts, it gives {'pos': {}, 'neg': {}}, as it was defined before the hash, unlike what I expect after the input I make. I am a total newbie so I might be ignoring some obvious points, sorry if that is the case.

Comment: ***"gives ... as it was defined before the hash,"***: This means your condition: `if a in pos1:` don't evaluate to `True`. Add a `print('if {} in {}:'.format(a, list(pos1)))` to see the values you are comparing.